# Multiple parameters in url to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking for a way to take in params from url into form.

`localhost:3000/person/param[1],param[2],param[3]...,param[n]`

If found, it will pull up the right page with the correct id/slug.

if not, it will redirect to and create a new page and insert the params into the right field.

**Example Usage:**

> **localhost:3000/person/1234,Tom,Tom_is_a_cool_guy**
>
> <1234 is not found so a new form is created>
>
> -new form-
>
> id: 1234
>
> name: Tom
>
> Text: Tom is a cool guy
>
> [Submit Button]

Currently I have it working when a new id is entered at the end, but it only takes in 1 param in the url.

```
  # GET /device_infos/1
# GET /device_infos/1.json
  def show
Rails.logger.info "inside persons_controller show"
if @person.nil?
  redirect_to action: "new", id: params[:id]
  return
end
# GET /persons/new
def new
   @person = Person.new
   @person.slug = params[:id]
end
```

Im very new to rails so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That isn't really how URLs are supposed to work in Rails. If you want to query with multiple values, you should be using the query string, something along the lines of `localhost:3000/person/1234?name=Tom&text=Tom+is+a+cool+guy`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, along with meagar's format of:

```
localhost:3000/person/1234?name=Tom&text=Tom+is+a+cool+guy
```

I added to the controller:

```
# GET /device_infos/1.json
def show
  Rails.logger.info "inside persons_controller show"
  if @person.nil?
     redirect_to action: "new", id: params[:id], name: params[:name], text: params[:text]
     return
end
# GET /persons/new
def new
   @person = Person.new
   @person.slug = params[:id]
   @person.name = params[:name]
   @person.text = params[:text]
end
```